# weird situation where undefined variable notice is raised

Tags: php

This simple line of my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['prodotto'])){$prodotto = $_POST['prodotto'];}else{$prodotto=='';}
```

is raising a php notice

> [php7:notice] [pid 47861] [client 10.211.55.2:63940] PHP Notice:
> Undefined variable: prodotto in /media/psf/Sites/login/login.php on
> line 44

but I was not expecting this to be raised since as far as I understand this line of code should always define it: using the posted value or an empty value. I know it is just a notice but I'd like to get rid of it too.

What am I missing here?

Further down on my code I reuse this variable like this:

```
die(json_encode(array('status'=>'success','message' => 'Benvenuto', 'prodotto'=>$prodotto, 'stripe_customer'=>$row['stripe_customer'])));
```

and again I get the same notice regarding `$prodotto` (that was set in the previous line of code shown!

Comment: You have `$prodotto == '';` instead of `$prodotto = '';`. Therefore, you are assigning a new variable in the `else` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are equating in else statement instead of initializing.

```
if(isset($_POST['prodotto'])){
    $prodotto = $_POST['prodotto'];
} else {
  $prodotto =''; // not ==
}
```

Or you can also

```
$prodotto = '';

if(isset($_POST['prodotto'])){
  $prodotto = $_POST['prodotto'];
} // avoid else
```

Or even better

```
 $prodotto = $_POST['prodotto'] ?? ''; // null coalescing operator
```

Comment: Or even better, and sidestepping any such issues, `$prodotto = $_POST['prodotto'] ?? '';`

Comment: @Jon thanks. That's a good hint!